# Something strange about self-defined emplace_back()

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I define a class to simulate Vector, here are some of the members:

```
template<typename T>
class Vec {
public:
       template<typename...Args>
       void emplace_back(Args&&... args);

private:
       std::pair<T*, T*> allocate_n_elements(const T*, const T*);
       void check_if_full();
       static std::allocator<T> admin;

       T* beginp;
       T* endp;
       T* borderp;
};

template<typename T>
std::allocator<T> Vec<T>::admin;

template<typename T> inline
std::pair<T*, T*> Vec<T>::allocate_n_elements(const T* pbegin, const T* pend) {
       auto newbeginp = admin.allocate(pend - pbegin);
       return{ newbeginp, std::uninitialized_copy(pbegin, pend, newbeginp) };
}
template<typename T> inline
void Vec<T>::check_if_full() {
       if (endp == borderp) {
              reallocate();
       }
}
template<typename T> inline
void Vec<T>::reallocate() {
       auto newsize = size() ? size() * 2 : 1;
       T* newbeginp = admin.allocate(newsize);
       T* newendp = newbeginp;
       T* old_index = beginp;
       for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
              admin.construct(newendp++, std::move(*old_index++));
       free();
       beginp = newbeginp;
       endp = newendp;
       borderp = beginp + newsize;
}

template<typename T>
template<typename...Args>
inline void Vec<T>::emplace_back(Args&&...args) {
       check_if_full();
       admin.construct(endp++, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

To test the public member emplace_back() on VS2015, I write code like this by mistake:

```
Vec<std::string> vs;
vs.emplace_back("dsa",(10,'a'));
std::cout << vs[0];
```

Surprisingly, the emplaced element is printed like this:

dsa     c : \ p r o g r a m   f i l e s   ( x 8 6 ) \ m i c r o s o f t   v i s u a l   s t u d i

So I'm curious why? Where's those "C:\program..." words from?

Comment: Aside from other UB which I suspect are in your code; `vs.emplace_back("dsa",(10,'a'));` The `(10, `a`)` will end up being a comma expression. where `'a'` is returned.

Comment: The words are most probably part of your programs debug information.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* tends to cause such problems. Like going outside of allocated memory. Take a look at [the `std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), read about the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator), and think about what happens when you construct a string like `std::string("dsa", 'a')`.